# Getting text only from a specific column of DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, cell

I have a DataGridView that is populated with 4 columns and multiple rows of data. I want to iterate through the DataGridView and get the cell value from *a specific column only*, since I need this data to pass into a method.

Here is my code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView2.Rows)
{                            
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        if (cell.Value == null || cell.Value.Equals(""))
        {
            continue;
        }

        GetQuestions(cell.Value.ToString());  
    }
}
```

This just seems to go through all the cells, however I need to be able to specify something like:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView2.Rows)
{                            
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells[2])//Note specified column index
    {
        if (cell.Value == null || cell.Value.Equals(""))
        {
            continue;
        }
        GetQuestions(cell.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't you just want to remove the inner `foreach` loop? Or have I missed something?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView2.Rows)
{                            
    DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[2]; //Note specified column index
    if (cell.Value == null || cell.Value.Equals(""))
    {
        continue;
    }

    GetQuestions(cell.Value.ToString());
}
```

Comment: It's the middle of the morning in my time zone, so you might need to return the favour in 12 hours time ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView2.Rows)
{
   DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells["foo"];//Note specified column NAME
   {
      if (cell != null && (cell.Value != null || !cell.Value.Equals("")))
      {
         GetQuestions(cell.Value.ToString());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you... I was searching for this piece of Code, though not in the same context...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could check the ColumnIndex? Would still loop through all the cells though.

```
if (cell.Value == null || cell.Value.Equals("") || cell.ColumnIndex != 2)
{
    continue;
}
```